# How to create a Record in a Model through another Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models, controllers

I am fairly new to Rails and I have a newbie question.

I have three models:

Users --< Clients --< Projects

To create a new Project I want to do this in my Project controller:

```
def create
  @project = current_user.projects.build(params[:project])
end
```

However, I always get an error saying that the client_id is missing, i.e. cannot be set in the Projects table I suppose.

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing here?

In my User model I have...

`has_many :projects, :through => :clients`

...which I thought should make

`@user.projects.build()`

work. But it doesn't.

Comment: did add this to your migration-file and did you run db:migrate?

Answer (score 1):

I think your projects table/model needs client_id which you are specifying using when you use

```
current_user.projects.build(params[:project])
```

I think you should be using using something like

```
active_project = current_user.active_project
active_project.clients.build(params[:project])
```

This is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

From your association, `Project` belongs to `Client` which belongs to `User`. You may want to look into re-designing.

But if you wish to keep the current design, you can fix this error in a couple ways

```
@client = Client.find params[:client]
@project = @user.project.build params[:project], :client_id => @client.id
```

OR

```
@project = @user.clients.find(params[:client]).projects.build(params[:project])
```

Either way, the User does not have projects. They have clients which in turn have projects. You may want to look into making the `Project` model a join model. In this case...

```
# user.rb
    has_many :clients, :through => :projects

# client.rb
    has_many :users, :through => :projects

# project.rb
    belongs_to :clients
    belongs_to :users
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. Why do you think my associations don't look right? In my application Users are supposed to manage their Clients which in turn can be allocated Projects. Is this not feasible?

Comment: Your second example works like a charme, even though I don't know how to get the client_id from a form (ideally a select box). It works very well when I provide a client_id manually though: `@project = current_user.clients.find(1).projects.build(params[:project])`

Comment: The first example you gave causes an error here: **Wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)**. And I think it only works with `@user.projects` rather than `@user.project`

Answer (score 1):

The problem when you make that call, is, *which* client does this build on?   Just building on `current_user.projects` doesn't provide this information.   To solve this though, we'd have to look at your form and/or routing to provide the information of which client to use.

For example, you could have the form actually start with a client and use nested resources in your form to then provide a new project.

Comment: Yes, I want to provide the `client_id` through a drop down select box but I don't know how to do that. How can this be done?

Comment: Check out these railscasts:  http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=nested

Comment: Thanks for the tip, found it quite useful!